# ui-router doesn't load states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, restangular

i have little problem with my code:

https://github.com/burnpiro/angular-blog

live version is available on http://erdem.pl/#/

Problem is that after deploying it on my server routing doesn't work. ui-router not even trying to load template or controller into ui-view. Application starts and configs are fired (tried with console.log). Even resolve option in home state is fired (PostService). But somehow it cannot load template. If i access template manually:

erdem.pl/components/home/home.html

it is there. The same with controller. If anyone have any ideas please let me know. It happened after deploy. Before that on my local machine it seems to work fine but now after getting project again and deploying it on my local it has the same error.

There is no JS errors or any network errors.

Thanks for help,

Comment: Inspect all requests in dev tools network. Perhaps paths need modifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but I think the issue is with the host you've set in your config.js file? This should be pointed to the public link for wherever your api lives. Should it be "http://erdem.pl"?

I've also noticed that Restangular doesn't seem to be sending your requests. I see that the execution gets into the RequestInterceptor, but I don't see them in the Network tab of my developer tools. This means that your promises from your `resolve` properties on your states will never be resolved. Your states are configured to wait for these `resolve` requests to resolve before initializing the controller and loading the template.

EDIT: I think I found the [issue](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/1303)!

Looks like Restangular is only compatible with Lodash 3.10, anything after that causes compatibility issues. Downgrade to 3.10 and hopefully it works for you!

Comment: I've checked that Restangular in PostService and after calling Restangular.one('posts') it returns object with all wrappers but after calling Restangular.one('posts').get() i'm not getting even promise. I've disabled all modules except home and services to be sure that none of them interrupts anything. Also removed errorInterceptor from app config. Have any idea why Restangular may not return promise after calling get()?

Comment: Ok, I think I might have found it? Is there a reason you use lodash instead of underscore.js? I found a JS error when trying to run `Restangular.one('posts').post('search', {limit: 11})` from the console that explained that _.contains() function was undefined. If you use underscore.js instead of lodash I think it might solve Restangular's problem. It seems as though it should work with both, but an update to either Restangular or Lodash has caused some incompatibility issues. If you really want to use Lodash, I'd suggest posting an issue on their GitHub page.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) That helps. I didn't even consider that was caused by lodash version.

Comment: The weird thing was that the error wasn't showing up in the console until I ran the command manually while in a breakpoint.